# JS or jQuery: How to automatically redirect to a url upon receiving a JSON object upon event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, events, addeventlistener

Goal is to be able to redirect to another url based upon an intersection within a cross-domain iframe.

Desired process is as such…

1. A user is on example.com/apps/ - and fills in a form which is within a cross-domain iframe.
2. Upon submitting this form within the iframe a `parent.postMessage()` art the end of the `load` event which posts a JSON string back to the current page.
3. Based in the information relied back the user is then redirected from the ‘parent’ site to a new url (also within parent site - eg. example.com/apps/foobar)

I have got as far as step 2 insofar as I am managing to get receipt of the JSON object but am struggling to then get the page to redirect as desired.

Any pointers will be gratefully received - am not at home with the level of JS I’m afraid

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

    var meta = JSON.stringify(event.data)
    var data = JSON.parse(meta);

    console.log(data);

    // this is the json object received once the form is submitted in the iframe { "applicantid": “12345”, "sector": “foobar” }
    // and this is the url I want the user to be automatically redirected to when the parent website received the json object
    // https://exampe.com/apps/sector/?applicantid=12345

    var applicantid  = data.applicantid; // 12345
    var sector       = data.sector;      // foobar

  if(applicantid !== undefined) {

    var url = 'https://exampe.com/apps/' + sector + '/?cand_id=' + applicantid + '/';
    $(location).attr('href',url);

   }
 });
});
```

(I am aware there a probably better ways to to do this - we are restricted to this (or a similar method) due to the organisational structure of the client)

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = 'https://url.com';
```

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Comment: Thank you - No joy I'm afraid - I think the issue is my function is not recognising when the Json vars become available